# Source for Nietzsche's question, "Which came first? Art or ethics?”

Tags: ethics, nietzsche, art

Memory suggests that Nietzsche's answer was ethics. Does anyone have a reference to the Nietzsche’s work where this question was posed?

Answer (score 1):

After typing some phrases up in Google Translate, and subsequently in the KSA, I believe it is in the "Private Publication" of *Socrates and the Greek Tragedy*, secondarily, perhaps, *The Birth of Tragedy*.